# htaccess redirect without user knowing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We are running multiple domains through the same code and we want to save their images in their respective folders. Here's what we are doing.

/images/www.domain1.com/logo.jpg
/images/www.domain2.com/logo.jpg

now, what I want to know is, is this possible in htaccess that we rewrite the urls without user suspecting anything. This is what I want that

```
<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />
```

should internally become through htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /images/{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But my question is,

1. The above redirect continually loops
2. Can I achieve the img effect without user or admin suspecting anything?

Sincerely,

Khuram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should not use `R` flag if you don't want to change URL in browser. However even without `R` flag your RewriteRule will loop infinitely and you will eventually get `internal server error`. Use RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ images/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC]
```

Which is using a special internal variable called `{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` that is set to 200 once RewriteRule rule is applied successfully.

Comment: Very well done Sir. This works perfectly. Thanks for teaching me a new trick.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `R=301` to simply do a rewrite rather than a redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /images/{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

The reason it's continually looping is that the 301 redirect causes a new request to be created for the url `images/www.domain1.com/logo.jpg`.  That URL also matches your `^images/(.*)$` rule, so it is redirected again, ad infinitum.

If you really want to do a 301 redirect (I suspect you don't, but if you did), you could solve the infinite looping problem by adding some rewrite conditions to skip the redirect if the domain is already included:

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^images/www.domain1.com/(.*)$
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^images/www.domain2.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /images/{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the explanation, I knew I was near but now I know why I am doing each of these steps. I will try and then mark this as finished.

Comment: Hi @Eric Anubhava's answer below did the trick. This one was again going for looping. Thanks again.